# binding two pickers and having unique values from both in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create 2 pickers, one when update the change in values of the second picker based on the index of the first picker...

When I change the value of the first picker, the second picker updates accordingly.

The issue? When I select an item from the second picker, I get `index out of range` error. The error is obvious, there are more items in the second picker then the first and they are both binded to the same dataset..

So, when $selectedSubsection changes in the first picker, the second picker get's the according data.

Now, how do I allow the second picker to make some choices on a new content so that $selectedSubsection doesn't change?

```
Picker(selection: $selectedSubsection, label: Text("Subsection")) {

ForEach(0 ..< self.subsections.count) {

Text(self.subsections[$0].name)

}}

Picker(selection: $selectedSubsection, label: Text("Subsection")) {

ForEach(0 ..< self.subsubsections.count) {

if self.subsubsections[$0].belongs_to == self.subsections[self.selectedSubsection].id

{

Text(self.subsubsections[$0].details)

}

}}
```

Also, how do I get the value from the second picker?

Comment: You should use two different `tag` value (integer) for two picker so the data from both picker won't conflict....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't know how to do that! I don't fully get what you mean?

Comment: okay no worries , tell me, have you used `storyboard` create pickers ??

Comment: yes in the past I have. keep in mind those this is SwiftUI

Comment: okay , Sorry then my friend ...I can help with `storyboard` but I don't know much about `SwiftUI`...so can't help you..

Comment: Well, how would you do this with storyboard? Perhaps I can port the answer.

Comment: okay, should I answer or just comment the answer (includes screenshot) ???

Comment: I think you should answer.